# How to add a stricter version of `findOne` which returns an error if record is not found for all models?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

In SailsJS for APIs, we fetch a resource and check whether it exists, before executing other logic.

How can I implement a function say `findOneStrict` in one place, for all models, which calls callback with some specific consistent error? Doesn't matter which, it just has to always be the same.
Such function would save lot of code duplication across API endpoints.

Ideally, it should have support to `populate` associations.

Sample current code:

```
sendSurpriseGift: function(req, res) {
  async.auto({
    user: function(callback) {
      User.findOne(userId).populate('hobby').exec(function(err, user) {
        if (err)
          return callback(err);
        if (!user)
          return callback({status: 'NOT_FOUND'});

        return callback(null, user);
      }
    }),
    sendGift: ['user', function(callback, results) {
      var user = results.user;
      // Gift sending logic
      // more logic
    }],
  }, function(err, results) {
       if (err) {
         if (err.status === 'NOT_FOUND') 
           return res.notFound(err);
         return res.serverError(err);
       }
       return res.ok({status: 'OK'});
  });
}
```

Comment: Any consistent error would work. Can you suggest something for MySQL?

Comment: I don't know Sails, but the ORM that is uses seems to have the option [to add class methods](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models/instance-class-methods.md#class-methods) to models. In which case you could write a generic `findOneStrict` implementation and use that for all your models.